Nuxt + JWT + WP: Using Nitro Server API
I’m currently working on a Nuxt 3 project with a headless WordPress setup using JWT for authentication. I have a couple of questions regarding best practices and specific implementation issues:
1. Why should I use Nuxt's Nitro API from the server/ folder instead of using classic front end API?
I'm aware that both can work, but I'm curious about the advantages (security, performance, etc.) of using the Nitro Server API approach.
2. Refresh Token Cookie Issue
I’m using the [JWT Authentication for WP][1] to handle authentication. According to the plugin documentation, to generate a new access token using the refresh token, I need to submit a POST request to the token refresh endpoint along with the refresh_token cookie intially get on login.
However, I’m struggling with managing this refresh token flow properly in my Nuxt app. Specifically:

How can I get the refresh_token cookie from the Nitro server fetch?
How should I store the cookie securely in my Nuxt app?
How can I pass this cookie along with another request to refresh the token later?

Has anyone implemented a similar workflow successfully? Thanks!
